# Has the actual behavior of FileStream.Lock(long, long) (or of the WINAPI method LockFile) changed since .NET 2.0 was originally released, and how?

Tags: .net, winapi, file-locking

I recently noticed that `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` is documented in [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.100).aspx) and [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.110).aspx) as reserving *exclusive* access to the specified range of the file by that "process" (but really for that FileStream instance or, rather, for the actual OS file handle it references internally).  The documentation for [.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.80).aspx) and [3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.85).aspx), on the other hand, indicate that the behavior is that it *prevents others from changing* the file (no writing to that range--even by the current FileStream/handle, I think, although that is not indicated) while *permitting read access* by all open FileStreams/handles (assuming the ShareMode allows such overlapping handles).  The documentation for [.NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.90).aspx) changes the wording to just "prevents others from changing" (can't write to the range); that may be a correction or clarification to the explanation of the behavior, or it may have been a transitional documentation which could really be met by either behavior (since it does not specify whether reads are permitted by others) without specifying whether other access or overlapping locks will be permitted or fail.

I thought that I had previously experimented with this API in .NET 2.0 and confirmed the lock-out of writes to the locked range even by the locking FileStream, but that was several years ago and my recollection may be faulty.... I may have simply relied on the documentation at the time, but I feel like I remember actually experimenting because I wanted to be sure to understand how it actually worked and because the documentation is fairly vague on some points.  However, Google did find [this thread from 2007](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1151637) on another site which seems to indicate that `LockFile` was not preventing read access the way one would expect for an "exclusive access" lock supported, ultimately, in the underlying OS.

However, recent experimentation (on a 64-bit machine running Windows 7) in both .NET 4.0- and .NET 2.0-targetted test applications found that both show the same *exclusive* behavior as described in the [documentation for .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.100).aspx).  I could not confirm the behavior as [originally documented for .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock(v=vs.80).aspx) and as I thought I remembered it behaving in the past.

A decompiler on the .NET 2.0 framework shows that `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` calls the WINAPI method [`LockFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx), and stepping into the .NET 4.0 framework finds that it calls the same WINAPI method from there, as well.  This WINAPI method is documented as reserving "exclusive access" in the documentation I found.  Was it previously documented as reserving shared read-only access?  Did it previously behave with shared read-only access back when .NET 2.0 was first released (particularly on Windows XP)?  Did its behavior perhaps change to exclusive access on Windows Vista or on Windows 7, or has it always behaved with exclusive access as it is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx)?

The WINAPI method [`LockFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx), on the other hand, takes a `dwFlags` parameter which can specify either shared (presumably read-only) or exclusive locking of the specified range.  Did the `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` method get changed by a patch to the .NET 2.0 framework at some point or has it always used `LockFile`?

Unfortunately, .NET does not provide an overload of `FileStream.Lock()` (or any other API that I have found) to access this selectable file-lock behavior, nor does it seem to have any other method to use the alternate mode from that used by `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` itself--except of course to hack a call down to the WINAPI method itself by a pInvoke... which is not allowable for some projects.

I'm hoping that someone will remember more definitively what the behavior actually used to be for the `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` method and/or for the underlying WINAPI method `LockFile` which it apparently calls (at least, in the most current version of .NET 2.0 and for .NET 4.x) or might know the history of these methods if they have changed their actual behavior the way the documented behavior seems to change between .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 and can clear up these glaring inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you couldn't hack down to pinvoke, but if you could, check out [ZwLockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566474(v=vs.85).aspx) which is the call that LockFile and LockFileEx end up calling.

As for behavior for LockFile around the Windows XP timeframe, I dug out my copy of MSDN from 2001:

**LockFile**

The **LockFile** function locks a region in an open file. Locking a region prevents other processes from accessing the region.

To specify additional options, use the LockFileEx function.

```
BOOL LockFile(
  HANDLE hFile,                   // handle to file
  DWORD dwFileOffsetLow,          // low-order word of offset
  DWORD dwFileOffsetHigh,         // high-order word of offset
  DWORD nNumberOfBytesToLockLow,  // low-order word of length
  DWORD nNumberOfBytesToLockHigh  // high-order word of length
);
```

**Parameters**

hFile

> [in] Handle to the file with a region to be locked. The file handle
>   must have been created with GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE access to
>   the file (or both).

dwFileOffsetLow

> [in] Specifies the low-order word of the starting byte offset in the
>   file where the lock should begin.

dwFileOffsetHigh

> [in] Specifies the high-order word of the starting byte offset in the
>   file where the lock should begin.  Windows 95/98/Me: dwFileOffsetHigh
>   must be 0, the sign extension of the value of dwFileOffsetLow. Any
>   other value will be rejected.

nNumberOfBytesToLockLow

> [in] Specifies the low-order word of the length of the byte range to
>   be locked.

nNumberOfBytesToLockHigh

> [in] Specifies the high-order word of the length of the byte range to
>   be locked.

**Return Values**

If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

**Remarks**

Locking a region of a file gives the locking process exclusive access to the specified region. File locks are not inherited by processes created by the locking process.

Locking a region of a file denies all other processes both read and write access to the specified region. Locking a region that goes beyond the current end-of-file position is not an error.

Locks may not overlap an existing locked region of the file.

If **LockFile** cannot lock a region of a file, it returns zero immediately. It does not block. To issue a file lock request that will block until the lock is acquired, use LockFileEx without LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY.

If a process terminates with a portion of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the locks are unlocked by the operating system. However, the time it takes for the operating system to unlock these locks depends upon available system resources. Therefore, it is recommended that your process explicitly unlock all files it has locked when it terminates. If this is not done, access to these files may be denied if the operating system has not yet unlocked them.

The UnlockFile function unlocks a file region locked by LockFile.

**Example Code**

For an example, see Reading, Writing, and Locking Files.

**Requirements**

> **Windows NT/2000/XP:** Included in Windows NT 3.1 and later.
>
> **Windows 95/98/Me:** Included in Windows 95 and later.
>
> **Header:** Declared in Winbase.h; include Windows.h.
>
> **Library:** Use Kernel32.lib.

**See Also**

File I/O Overview, File I/O Functions, CreateFile, LockFileEx, UnlockFile

**Platform SDK Release:** August 2001

Comment: Okay, so the 2001 documentation claims that the WINAPI LockFile function used the "exclusive" behavior.  (Is it still consistent with that around 2007-2010?)  Thanks for the answer on that! (+1)  That still leaves the question of whether .NET 2.0 originally/always used WINAPI LockFile and the described exclusive behavior or (at some point) used WINAPI LockFileEx and non-exclusive (write-protect) behavior and later changed (?...?) to using LockFile and exclusive behavior.

Comment: Early dotnet was built on top of the existing WINAPI (interop wrappers basically).  I used the early beta of the .NET framework on through 2.0.  When we asked for support for such-and-such WINAPI that wasn't covered, they told us to interop, as that was basically what most of the framework did: provide safe interop wrappers.  So I am going out on a limb and saying that yes, it used the WINAPI LockFile.